# DataBind a Simple String Property to Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a Simple Property called **Customer** as string
I want to bind this property to a Textbox.Text Databinding
I use the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

If I want to add the Databindings with

`TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Customer, "Text")`

I get an Error with:

> You cannot bind text to the property or column for the DataSource.
> Parameter name: dataMember

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _Customer As String = "DEFAULT"
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Customer, "Text")
    End Sub

    Public Property Customer As String
        Get
            Return _Customer
        End Get
        Set
            _Customer = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to establish the binding in code instead of in the XAML?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? Please apply all tags that are relevant.

Comment: Your property doesn't really make sense on the form. You generally bind some other object that exists to hold the data. The second argument to Add should be that object and the third argument is the name of the property.

Comment: Hi, yes im Using Windows Forms. The Reason why i estalish the binding in the code instead of XAML is i dont know how to do it better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you can't bind to a property directly, you need to bind to an object which contains the property. Also you can't use a property that is inside the Form1 class. You need to set up an instance of an object.

I've created a sample that uses a class named Customer with a single property called Name. I've also created a base class. This is not required, but is useful if you create multiple classes.

```
Public Class BaseNotify
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Friend Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Friend Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Customer
    Inherits BaseNotify

    Private _name As String = "DEFAULT"

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set
            If (_name = Value) Then Return
            _name = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Finally set up the form (I also renamed the textbox to something more meaningful.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _customer As Customer

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        BindProperties()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindProperties()
        _customer = New Customer()
        Me.tbName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _customer, NameOf(Customer.Name))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Using *NameOf* is recommended, as it won't break the code if you decide to change the property name at a later stage.

Comment: "The reason is that you can't bind to a property directly, you need to bind to an object which contains the property. " Okay good to know. I already thought that I was doing something fundamentally wrong.